# How to load bootstrap modal content via AJAX in MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to load the contents of the modal using AJAX. Here is the code snippet what I am trying to do.

Index.cshtml

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Create()">Create</button>
```

index.js

```
function AddTask() {
   $Modal = $('#myModal')
   $.get('/Customer/Create', function (data) {
      $Modal.modal({ show: true });
   });
}
```

Customer Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return PartialView();
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>My modal content here…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I load the Create.cshtml contents in the modal?

Comment: Thank you for your input but didn't work. It didn't work as a modal.

Comment: you have `Create()` in the `onclick` event on your button, but the function you want to call is named `AddTask` - is that a typo in your question, or is that actually your code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should work for you, although, I'm not sure about the `type="submit"`

```
<button type="submit" href="@Url.Action("Create","Customer")"
  class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create</button>
```

or

```
<button type="submit" data-remote="@Url.Action("Create","Customer")"
  class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create</button>
```

Although, this has been depreciated, so you'll need to do it manually in version 4 (or write your own extension to handle this like it did in 3.x)

I believe you'll also need to remove `<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">` and the last `</div>` from Create.cshtml, as these belong in your parent page (Index.cshtml).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. Suppose We get partial view for modal content.Instead of get method

```
function AddTask() {
   $Modal = $('#myModal');
   $Modal.load('/Customer/Create');
   $Modal.modal('show');
}
```

Note: Here i used bootstrap 2.3.2.I hope you can get idea of this.